# How Do I Make aTextBlock Blink Only When a Dependency Property of the ViewModel Has a Certain Value?

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have a View Model object that has a depednency property called `IsSearching`; it is a `bool`.  My form has a `TextBlock` control that is used to display the number of matching rows.  The property that is bound to the `TextBlock's` `Text` property is an  `int?` type.  At the start of the search, the property is set to `null`.  The converter in the binding displays this as "--".

I want the "--" string to flash while the `IsSearching` property is `true`, and I don't want it flash when it is `false`.  Here's what I have so far:

The `StoryBoard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FlashTextBlockText">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"   Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

A named `Style` for `TextBlocks` only:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" x:Key="FlashBlockText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSearching}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashTextBlockText}" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The `IsSearching` property is initially `false`.  When the user clicks on the Search `Button`, it is set to true and the flashing begins.  But it doesn't stop flashing.

How do I get the `StoryBoard` to stop when `IsSearching` is set back to `false`?

Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggers operating on property values have two collections containing actions:

- EnterActions: Actions in this collection are activated when the trigger itself is activated (in your example when IsSearching becomes true)
- ExitActions: Actions in here are activated when the trigger is deactivated (IsSearching becomes false)

So you should just stop the storyboard by adding a StopStoryboard action inside the ExitActions collection.

There is no need to create a new DataTrigger where you explicitly check whether the property has become false.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSearching}" Value="True"> 
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="storyboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashTextBlockText}" />
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="storyboard" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That also works and is cleaner than the solutions.  I've modified my code to use this method.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You're solution is cleaner. Learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

You need a DataTrigger for when IsSearching = False. With that you can do a StopStoryboard.

Here's an example:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSearching}" Value="false">
     <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="YourBeginStoryboard" />
     </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

*Flash aaaahhhh! Savior of the universe!*

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  I didn't know about the StopStoryBoard class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding another DataTrigger for when the value is False, and then having another storyboard, where you just have the visiblity as visible?